# Increase Subscription price in google play

Tags: google-play, subscription

I have put a new subscription price in my in app products on my Google apps and activated the new price. How do I link this to my apps and get the new price into the google store?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for implementing a subscription-type in-app-purchase in your application?

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#Subs

Answer (score 4):

Since October 2018 you can edit the price of the subscription.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can use firebase remote configuration (need to implement this).
2. you can change the price on Google Play.